# How to do something like #Card%{ } in CSS

Tags: css

This is my css :

```
<div id="Card0">
  <div draggable="true" id="carte">
    <div id="no">8</div>
    <div id="Trefle"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I will have Card1, Card2 ...

I would like to do something like  #Card%{ } 
Is it possible?

Comment: As far as I know, you can not do any scripting in CSS. You should have two classes: `card` for all cards and `card1`, `card2` for specific cards.

Comment: @TomášZato beat me to it :) So: Seconded.

Comment: If they are all the same, classes is the way to go. Otherwise you have to take a look at JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unquestionably you would use a class for this:

```
<div id="Card0" class="card">
  <div draggable="true" id="carte0">
    <div id="no">8</div>
    <div id="Trefle"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="Card1" class="card">
  <div draggable="true" id="carte1">
    <div id="no">8</div>
    <div id="Trefle"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div id="Card2" class="card">
  <div draggable="true" id="carte2">
    <div id="no">8</div>
    <div id="Trefle"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Did not know I could have both id and class on an element

Answer (score 1):

As Tomas and Joe already commented, you can't really do any scripting in pure CSS. You could do any of the following:

- Give every card a class and target that - this is probably the best way.
- Put all cards in a container and then use something like `#cards > div`.
- Use a preprocessor like LESS or SASS, they take less/sass scripts and compile them into regular CSS files.
- Use `div[id^=Card]` to target every div which ID begins with "Card".